# Using InterfaceBuilder ONLY for positioning objects on the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uibutton

Have created a `UIButton` programmatically, all works as expected but how can I use the IB ONLY for positioning the objects on the view?

To be more precise I like to use the IB for this line only (see: setViaIB)

```
 self.searchBtn.frame = CGRectMake(setViaIB, setViaIB, 36, 36);
```

Full code for `UIButton` creation:

```
 self.searchBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 self.searchBtn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 36, 36);
[self.searchBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.searchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(searchBtnTapped::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.searchBtn setNeedsDisplay];
[self.view addSubview:self.searchBtn];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, why don't you use `initWithNibName: bundle:` to create the whole view in an nib (Interface Builder) file?

Comment: Just to be more flexible. Don't like IB that much because it hides code.

Comment: IB was designed for that reason, so that your code could be kept separate from the UI design.

Answer (score 0):

You can only position the button in IB if you created it in IB. You can change searchBtnTapped method to an IBAction and link it up to your button via files owner in IB. You can then move the button wherever you want in IB. If not you will just have to reposition the button via coordinates until you are happy.